# Im making a autorole discord bot, but it only gives roles to himself, and doesnt react at all when i react

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.guilds = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
token = ''
flash_channel_id = 
flash_log_channel_id = 
reaction_roles_channel_id = 
your_user_id = 
emoji_to_role = {
    '⬛': 1144708657540497500,
    '⬜': 1144711799401369600,
    '': 1144709060256612464,
    '': 1144709483289907230,
    '': 1144709232852209764,
    '❤️': 1144709299508105309,
    '': 1144712432091140286,
    '': 1144712267699601408,
    '': 1144709619743211603,
    '': 1144709700408057896,
    '': 1144710086510518302,
    '': 1144711426045399192,
    '': 1144711270403162242,
    '': 1144710368501969036,
}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')
    await send_display_message_if_missing()

async def send_display_message_if_missing():
    channel = bot.get_channel(reaction_roles_channel_id)
    messages = [msg async for msg in channel.history(limit=10)]
    
    display_message_exists = any("Welcome to the server!" in msg.content for msg in messages)
    if not display_message_exists:
        await forward_roles_message()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == flash_channel_id and not message.author.bot:
        await forward_message_to_log(message)
        await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
        await asyncio.sleep(55)
        await message.add_reaction('⏰')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        try:
            reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji='1️⃣')
            await reaction.remove(bot.user)
            reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji='2️⃣')
            await reaction.remove(bot.user)
            await message.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def display(ctx):
    await forward_roles_message()

async def forward_roles_message():
    channel = bot.get_channel(reaction_roles_channel_id)
    flash_role_id = 
    if channel:
        display_message = (
            "Welcome to the server!\n"
            f"React to this message with the emojis to get the corresponding roles:\n"
            # Emojis and roles here
        )
        msg = await channel.send(display_message)
        for emoji in emoji_to_role.keys():
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == reaction_roles_channel_id:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        if user:
            emoji = payload.emoji.name
            role_id = emoji_to_role.get(emoji)
            if role_id:
                role = guild.get_role(role_id)
                if role:
                    try:
                        await user.add_roles(role)
                        print(f"Role {role.name} added to {user.name}")
                    except discord.Forbidden:
                        print("Missing permissions to assign role.")
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


bot.run(token)
```

Im kinda noob so dont judge, the bot has also a flash channel, it works alright, whats not working is the autoroles.

im using discord.py, and the bot has administrator perms.

the bot only adds roles to himself, when my or anyone from my server reacts it doesnt do anything, it doesnt even print on the terminal.

im still really new to bot coding, sorry about bad code or any dumb errors, appreciate the help

Comment: You need to enable intents.members.